# substore redirect to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a URL like below

http://www.abcxyz.com/storename

and I have sub-domain with

http://subdomain.adbxyz.com

So I want to rewrite all URLs of http://www.abcxyz.com/storename with http://subdomain.adbxyz.com/

How can I do this using HTACCESS?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `mod_alias` and want to do just a permanent redirect then you can add the following line to your `.htaccess`:

```
Redirect 301 /www.abcxyz.com/storename http://subdomain.adbxyz.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't internally rewrite from one host (`www.abcxyz.com`) to another (`subdomain.abcxyz.com`) without using a reverse proxy. "Rewrite" means to change the URI internally on the server (or "behind the scenes") such that the browser or client doesn't know about it, the URL in the browser's address bar remains unchanged. To do this, using mod_rewrite in conjunction with mod_proxy:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?storename(.*)$ http://subdomain.adbxyz.com/$1 [L,P]
```

If what you mean is a "redirect", as in the request is made, and the response is to tell the browser or client to go to a different place, thus changing the browser's URL address bar, then that's simpler:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?storename(.*)$ http://subdomain.adbxyz.com/$1 [L,R]
```

This would go in the document root of the `www.abcxyz.com` vhost/server.